# Cypress - Or Condition on Drop Down Button List

Tags: automation, cypress

I have a current Cypress check that iterates over a set of dropdowns checking for the case that the dropdown has 'Never eligible to update' as a value. However, I have to change the app so that one dropdown has  'Updates Sometimes'.
I need to modify this test so that it passes if either of those two values is in the drop-down list. Not sure how to OR this.

```js
cy.get("@updateRules")
  .find("button")
  .each(button => expect(button).to.contain("Never eligible to update"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Possibly the simplest is regex

```js
cy.get("@updateRules")
  .find("button")
  .each($button => {
    cy.wrap($button).contains(/Never eligible to update|Updates Sometimes/)
  })
```

or

```js
cy.get("@updateRules")
  .find("button")
  .each($button => {
    expect($button).to.match(/Never eligible to update|Updates Sometimes/)
  })
```

---

Chai has a [satisfy](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_satisfy) method

```js
cy.get("@updateRules")
  .find("button")
  .each($button => expect($button.text()).to.satisfy(text => {
      return text.includes('Never eligible to update') || 
             text.includes('Updates Sometimes')
    })
  )
```

---

jQuery OR condition uses a comma between alternate values.

You will need to shift `.contains()` to `:contains()` inside the selector.

```js
cy.get("@updateRules")
  .its('length')
  .then(ruleCount => {
    cy.get("@updateRules")
      .find("button:contains('Never eligible to update'), button:contains('Updates Sometimes')")
      .its('length')
      .then(matchCount => expect(ruleCount).to.eq(matchCount))
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a chai assertion `.oneOf` which asserts that the target is a member of the given array list.

```js
cy.get("@updateRules")
  .find("button")
  .each($button => {
    expect($button.text().trim()).to.be.oneOf(["Never eligible to update", "Updates Sometimes"])
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `OR` match it using RegEx:

```js
cy.get("@updateRules")
  .find("button")
  .each($button => {
    cy.wrap($button).contains(/Never eligible to update|Updates Sometimes/g)
  })
```

Comment: This is the same as my answer.